# getFieldValue failed upon organizing a case

Tags: wordpress, error, civicase, core

When clicking on "manage case" in the case tab of any contact, I get the error message "getFieldValue failed". I can use all other parts of CiviCase, but don't see a possibility to set the case status, assign case coordinators or such.

This is a rather fresh Wordpress-CiviCRM 5.26.2. The organize case - functionality was never tested on this install. It might have been broken on install already, or might have come in place through settings during setup.

I couldn't find out which FieldValue throws the error. Any hints where to look or even plain solutions?
The Log Entry doesn't mention CiviCase at all, rather points at Core.

Log Entry:

```
[debug] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(419): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 /var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1535): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#3 /var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#4 /var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#5 /var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#6 /var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-admin/admin.php(254): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#7 {main}
```

The error message via mail reads (just the beginning of the message):

```
***ERROR***
message:            getFieldValue failed
code:                
exception:          CRM_Core_Exception Object
(
    [errorData:CRM_Core_Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [error_code] => 0
        )

    [cause:protected] => 
    [_trace:PEAR_Exception:private] => 
    [message:protected] => getFieldValue failed
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php
    [line:protected] => 1252
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
```

DAO.php line 1252 (throw new...) is preceded by a comment in the code:

```
      public static function getFieldValue($daoName, $searchValue, $returnColumn = 'name', $searchColumn = 'id', $force = FALSE) {
    if (
      empty($searchValue) ||
      trim(strtolower($searchValue)) == 'null'
    ) {
      // adding this here since developers forget to check for an id
      // or for the 'null' (which is a bad DAO kludge)
      // and hence we get the first value in the db
      throw new CRM_Core_Exception('getFieldValue failed');
    }
```

full Log Entry (I had to delete the last 2,500 characters due to the maximum post length of 30,000 characters):

```
 [error] 
$Fatal Error Details = array(3) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(20) "getFieldValue failed"
  ["code"]=>
  NULL
  ["exception"]=>
  object(CRM_Core_Exception)#15747 (10) {
    ["errorData":"CRM_Core_Exception":private]=>
    array(1) {
      ["error_code"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["cause":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_trace":"PEAR_Exception":private]=>
    NULL
    ["message":protected]=>
    string(20) "getFieldValue failed"
    ["string":"Exception":private]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["code":protected]=>
    int(0)
    ["file":protected]=>
    string(85) "/var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php"
    ["line":protected]=>
    int(1252)
    ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
    array(14) {
      [0]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(103) "/var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Activity/Selector/Activity.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(133)
        ["function"]=>
        string(13) "getFieldValue"
        ["class"]=>
        string(12) "CRM_Core_DAO"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(4) {
          [0]=>
          string(32) "CRM_Event_BAO_ParticipantPayment"
          [1]=>
          NULL
          [2]=>
          string(14) "participant_id"
          [3]=>
          string(15) "contribution_id"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(103) "/var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Activity/Selector/Activity.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(425)
        ["function"]=>
        string(11) "actionLinks"
        ["class"]=>
        string(30) "CRM_Activity_Selector_Activity"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(5) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "46"
          [1]=>
          NULL
          [2]=>
          bool(false)
          [3]=>
          string(3) "126"
          [4]=>
          NULL
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(101) "/var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(404)
        ["function"]=>
        string(7) "getRows"
        ["class"]=>
        string(30) "CRM_Activity_Selector_Activity"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(6) {
          [0]=>
          int(4)
          [1]=>
          int(0)
          [2]=>
          int(50)
          [3]=>
          object(CRM_Utils_Sort)#15794 (7) {
            ["_name":protected]=>
            NULL
            ["_vars"]=>
            array(5) {
              [2]=>
              array(3) {
                ["name"]=>
                string(13) "activity_type"
                ["direction"]=>
                int(4)
                ["title"]=>
                string(3) "Typ"
              }
              [3]=>
              array(3) {
                ["name"]=>
                string(7) "subject"
                ["direction"]=>
                int(4)
                ["title"]=>
                string(14) "Thema, Betreff"
              }
              [4]=>
              array(3) {
                ["name"]=>
                string(19) "source_contact_name"
                ["direction"]=>
                int(4)
                ["title"]=>
                string(16) "Hinzugefügt von"
              }
              [5]=>
              array(3) {
                ["name"]=>
                string(18) "activity_date_time"
                ["direction"]=>
                int(4)
                ["title"]=>
                string(5) "Datum"
              }
              [6]=>
              array(3) {
                ["name"]=>
                string(9) "status_id"
                ["direction"]=>
                int(4)
                ["title"]=>
                string(6) "Status"
              }
            }
            ["_link":protected]=>
            string(245) "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview%2Fcase&page=CiviCRM&reset=1&id=5&cid=50&action=view&context=case&selectedChild=case&key=0c9e913e0fc67c8f00c1438c5692e3d7_6103&force=1&crmSID="
            ["_urlVar":protected]=>
            string(6) "crmSID"
            ["_currentSortID":protected]=>
            int(1)
            ["_currentSortDirection":protected]=>
            NULL
            ["_response"]=>
            array(5) {
              ["activity_type"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["link"]=>
                string(282) "Typ"
              }
              ["subject"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["link"]=>
                string(293) "Thema, Betreff"
              }
              ["source_contact_name"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["link"]=>
                string(295) "Hinzugefügt von"
              }
              ["activity_date_time"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["link"]=>
                string(284) "Datum"
              }
              ["status_id"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["link"]=>
                string(285) "Status"
              }
            }
          }
          [4]=>
          int(1)
          [5]=>
          int(5)
        }
      }
      [3]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(101) "/var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(326)
        ["function"]=>
        string(7) "getRows"
        ["class"]=>
        string(28) "CRM_Core_Selector_Controller"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          object(CRM_Core_Selector_Controller)#15563 (18) {
            ["_object":protected]=>
            object(CRM_Activity_Selector_Activity)#15778 (8) {
              ["_contactId":protected]=>
              int(50)
              ["_admin":protected]=>
              bool(false)
              ["_context":protected]=>
              string(4) "case"
              ["_activityTypeIDs":protected]=>
              NULL
              ["_viewOptions":protected]=>
              array(13) {
                ["activity"]=>
                int(1)
                ["rel"]=>
                int(1)
                ["group"]=>
                int(1)
                ["note"]=>
                int(1)
                ["tag"]=>
                int(1)
                ["log"]=>
                int(1)
                ["CiviContribute (Zuwendungen)"]=>
                int(1)
                ["CiviMember (Mitgliederverwaltung)"]=>
                int(1)
                ["CiviEvent"]=>
                int(1)
                ["CiviCase (Fallmanagement)"]=>
                int(1)
                ["CiviGrant (Bewilligungen)"]=>
                int(0)
                ["CiviPledge (Unterstützungszusagen)"]=>
                int(1)
                ["CiviMail"]=>
                int(1)
              }
              ["_order":protected]=>
              &array(5) {
                [2]=>
                &array(3) {
                  ["name"]=>
                  string(3) "Typ"
                  ["sort"]=>
                  string(13) "activity_type"
                  ["direction"]=>
                  int(4)
                }
                [3]=>
                &array(3) {
                  ["name"]=>
                  string(14) "Thema, Betreff"
                  ["sort"]=>
                  string(7) "subject"
                  ["direction"]=>
                  int(4)
                }
                [4]=>
                &array(3) {
                  ["name"]=>
                  string(16) "Hinzugefügt von"
                  ["sort"]=>
                  string(19) "source_contact_name"
                  ["direction"]=>
                  int(4)
                }
                [5]=>
                &array(3) {
                  ["name"]=>
                  string(5) "Datum"
                  ["sort"]=>
                  string(18) "activity_date_time"
                  ["direction"]=>
                  int(4)
                }
                [6]=>
                &array(3) {
                  ["name"]=>
                  string(6) "Status"
                  ["sort"]=>
                  string(9) "status_id"
                  ["direction"]=>
                  int(4)
                }
              }
              ["_permission":protected]=>
              NULL
              ["_key":protected]=>
              NULL
            }
            ["_sort":protected]=>
            object(CRM_Utils_Sort)#15794 (7) {
              ["_name":protected]=>
              NULL
              ["_vars"]=>
              array(5) {
                [2]=>
                array(3) {
                  ["name"]=>
                  string(13) "activity_type"
                  ["direction"]=>
                  int(4)
                  ["title"]=>
                  string(3) "Typ"
                }
                [3]=>
                array(3) {
                  ["name"]=>
                  string(7) "subject"
                  ["direction"]=>
                  int(4)
                  ["title"]=>
                  string(14) "Thema, Betreff"
                }
                [4]=>
                array(3) {
                  ["name"]=>
                  string(19) "source_contact_name"
                  ["direction"]=>
                  int(4)
                  ["title"]=>
                  string(16) "Hinzugefügt von"
                }
                [5]=>
                array(3) {
                  ["name"]=>
                  string(18) "activity_date_time"
                  ["direction"]=>
                  int(4)
                  ["title"]=>
                  string(5) "Datum"
                }
                [6]=>
                array(3) {
                  ["name"]=>
                  string(9) "status_id"
                  ["direction"]=>
                  int(4)
                  ["title"]=>
                  string(6) "Status"
                }
              }
              ["_link":protected]=>
              string(245) "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview%2Fcase&page=CiviCRM&reset=1&id=5&cid=50&action=view&context=case&selectedChild=case&key=0c9e913e0fc67c8f00c1438c5692e3d7_6103&force=1&crmSID="
              ["_urlVar":protected]=>
              string(6) "crmSID"
              ["_currentSortID":protected]=>
              int(1)
              ["_currentSortDirection":protected]=>
              NULL
              ["_response"]=>
              array(5) {
                ["activity_type"]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["link"]=>
                  string(282) "Typ"
                }
                ["subject"]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["link"]=>
                  string(293) "Thema, Betreff"
                }
                ["source_contact_name"]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["link"]=>
                  string(295) "Hinzugefügt von"
                }
                ["activity_date_time"]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["link"]=>
                  string(284) "Datum"
                }
                ["status_id"]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["link"]=>
                  string(285) "Status"
                }
              }
            }
            ["_sortID":protected]=>
            NULL
            ["_sortOrder":protected]=>
            &array(5) {
              [2]=>
              &array(3) {
                ["name"]=>
                string(3) "Typ"
                ["sort"]=>
                string(13) "activity_type"
                ["direction"]=>
                int(4)
              }
              [3]=>
              &array(3) {
                ["name"]=>
                string(14) "Thema, Betreff"
                ["sort"]=>
                string(7) "subject"
                ["direction"]=>
                int(4)
              }
              [4]=>
              &array(3) {
                ["name"]=>
                string(16) "Hinzugefügt von"
                ["sort"]=>
                string(19) "source_contact_name"
                ["direction"]=>
                int(4)
              }
              [5]=>
              &array(3) {
                ["name"]=>
                string(5) "Datum"
                ["sort"]=>
                string(18) "activity_date_time"
                ["direction"]=>
                int(4)
              }
              [6]=>
              &array(3) {
                ["name"]=>
                string(6) "Status"
                ["sort"]=>
                string(9) "status_id"
                ["direction"]=>
                int(4)
              }
            }
            ["_pager":protected]=>
            object(CRM_Utils_Pager)#15774 (64) {
              ["_response"]=>
              array(13) {
                ["first"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["back"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["next"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["last"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["currentPage"]=>
                int(1)
                ["numPages"]=>
                int(1)
                ["csvString"]=>
                NULL
                ["status"]=>
                string(26) "Aktivitäten 1 - 24 von 24"
                ["buttonTop"]=>
                string(14) "PagerTopButton"
                ["buttonBottom"]=>
                string(17) "PagerBottomButton"
                ["currentLocation"]=>
                string(194) "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview%2Fcase&page=CiviCRM&id=5&cid=50&action=view&context=case&selectedChild=case&key=0c9e913e0fc67c8f00c1438c5692e3d7_6103&force=1&crmPID=1"
                ["titleTop"]=>
                string(80) "Seite  von 1"
                ["titleBottom"]=>
                string(82) "Seite  von 1"
              }
              ["_totalItems"]=>
              int(24)
              ["_perPage"]=>
              int(50)
              ["_delta"]=>
              int(1)
              ["_currentPage"]=>
              int(1)
              ["_totalPages"]=>
              float(1)
              ["_linkClass"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["_classString"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["_path"]=>
              string(9) "/wp-admin"
              ["_fileName"]=>
              string(9) "admin.php"
              ["_fixFileName"]=>
              bool(true)
              ["_append"]=>
              bool(true)
              ["_httpMethod"]=>
              string(3) "GET"
              ["_formID"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["_importQuery"]=>
              bool(true)
              ["_urlVar"]=>
              string(6) "crmPID"
              ["_linkData"]=>
              array(10) {
                ["page"]=>
                string(7) "CiviCRM"
                ["q"]=>
                string(25) "civicrm/contact/view/case"
                ["id"]=>
                string(1) "5"
                ["cid"]=>
                string(2) "50"
                ["action"]=>
                string(4) "view"
                ["context"]=>
                string(4) "case"
                ["selectedChild"]=>
                string(4) "case"
                ["key"]=>
                string(37) "0c9e913e0fc67c8f00c1438c5692e3d7_6103"
                ["noheader"]=>
                bool(true)
                ["force"]=>
                string(1) "1"
              }
              ["_extraVars"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["force"]=>
                string(1) "1"
              }
              ["_excludeVars"]=>
              array(3) {
                [0]=>
                string(5) "reset"
                [1]=>
                string(7) "snippet"
                [2]=>
                string(7) "section"
              }
              ["_expanded"]=>
              bool(true)
              ["_accesskey"]=>
              bool(false)
              ["_attributes"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["_onclick"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["_altFirst"]=>
              string(10) "first page"
              ["_altPrev"]=>
              string(13) "previous page"
              ["_altNext"]=>
              string(9) "next page"
              ["_altLast"]=>
              string(9) "last page"
              ["_altPage"]=>
              string(7) "page %d"
              ["_prevImg"]=>
              string(17) "  < Vorheriger"
              ["_prevImgEmpty"]=>
              NULL
              ["_nextImg"]=>
              string(15) "Nächster > "
              ["_nextImgEmpty"]=>
              NULL
              ["_separator"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["_spacesBeforeSeparator"]=>
              int(1)
              ["_spacesAfterSeparator"]=>
              int(1)
              ["_curPageLinkClassName"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["_curPageSpanPre"]=>
              string(3) ""
              ["_curPageSpanPost"]=>
              string(4) ""
              ["_firstPagePre"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["_firstPageText"]=>
              string(17) "  << Erster"
              ["_firstPagePost"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["_lastPagePre"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["_lastPageText"]=>
              string(18) "Letzter >>  "
              ["_lastPagePost"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["_spacesBefore"]=>
              string(6) " "
              ["_spacesAfter"]=>
              string(6) " "
              ["_firstLinkTitle"]=>
              string(10) "first page"
              ["_nextLinkTitle"]=>
              string(9) "next page"
              ["_prevLinkTitle"]=>
              string(13) "previous page"
              ["_lastLinkTitle"]=>
              string(9) "last page"
              ["_showAllText"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["_itemData"]=>
              NULL
              ["_clearIfVoid"]=>
              bool(true)
              ["_useSessions"]=>
              bool(false)
              ["_closeSession"]=>
              bool(false)
              ["_sessionVar"]=>
              string(10) "setPerPage"
              ["_pearErrorMode"]=>
              NULL
              ["links"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["linkTags"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["linkTagsRaw"]=>
              array(4) {
                ["first"]=>
                array(0) {
                }
                ["prev"]=>
                array(0) {
                }
                ["next"]=>
                array(0) {
                }
                ["last"]=>
                array(0) {
                }
              }
              ["range"]=>
              array(0) {
              }
              ["_allowed_options"]=>
              array(51) {
                [0]=>
                string(10) "totalItems"
                [1]=>
                string(7) "perPage"
                [2]=>
                string(5) "delta"
                [3]=>
                string(9) "linkClass"
                [4]=>
                string(4) "path"
                [5]=>
                string(8) "fileName"
                [6]=>
                string(11) "fixFileName"
                [7]=>
                string(6) "append"
                [8]=>
                string(10) "httpMethod"
                [9]=>
                string(6) "formID"
                [10]=>
                string(11) "importQuery"
                [11]=>
                string(6) "urlVar"
                [12]=>
                string(8) "altFirst"
                [13]=>
                string(7) "altPrev"
                [14]=>
                string(7) "altNext"
                [15]=>
                string(7) "altLast"
                [16]=>
                string(7) "altPage"
                [17]=>
                string(7) "prevImg"
                [18]=>
                string(12) "prevImgEmpty"
                [19]=>
                string(7) "nextImg"
                [20]=>
                string(12) "nextImgEmpty"
                [21]=>
                string(8) "expanded"
                [22]=>
                string(9) "accesskey"
                [23]=>
                string(10) "attributes"
                [24]=>
                string(7) "onclick"
                [25]=>
                string(9) "separator"
                [26]=>
                string(21) "spacesBeforeSeparator"
                [27]=>
                string(20) "spacesAfterSeparator"
                [28]=>
                string(20) "curPageLinkClassName"
                [29]=>
                string(14) "curPageSpanPre"
                [30]=>
                string(15) "curPageSpanPost"
                [31]=>
                string(12) "firstPagePre"
                [32]=>
                string(13) "firstPageText"
                [33]=>
                string(13) "firstPagePost"
                [34]=>
                string(11) "lastPagePre"
                [35]=>
                string(12) "lastPageText"
                [36]=>
                string(12) "lastPagePost"
                [37]=>
                string(14) "firstLinkTitle"
                [38]=>
                string(13) "nextLinkTitle"
                [39]=>
                string(13) "prevLinkTitle"
                [40]=>
                string(13) "lastLinkTitle"
                [41]=>
                string(11) "showAllText"
                [42]=>
                string(8) "itemData"
                [43]=>
                string(11) "clearIfVoid"
                [44]=>
                string(11) "useSessions"
                [45]=>
                string(12) "closeSession"
                [46]=>
                string(10) "sessionVar"
                [47]=>
                string(13) "pearErrorMode"
                [48]=>
                string(9) "extraVars"
                [49]=>
                string(11) "excludeVars"
                [50]=>
                string(11) "currentPage"
              }
              ["_url"]=>
              string(19) "/wp-admin/admin.php"
              ["_pageData"]=>
              array(0) {
              }
            }
            ["_pageID":protected]=>
            int(1)
            ["_pagerOffset":protected]=>
            int(0)
            ["_pagerRowCount":protected]=>
            int(50)
            ["_total":protected]=>
            int(24)
            ["_action":protected]=>
            int(4)
            ["_content":protected]=>
            NULL
            ["_embedded":protected]=>
            bool(true)
            ["_print":protected]=>
            bool(false)
            ["_store":protected]=>
            object(CRM_Case_Page_Tab)#15483 (13) {
              ["_permission"]=>
              NULL
              ["_contactId"]=>
              int(50)
              ["_name":protected]=>
              string(17) "CRM_Case_Page_Tab"
              ["_title":protected]=>
              string(4) "Fall"
              ["_mode":protected]=>
              string(4) "null"
              ["_embedded":protected]=>
              bool(false)
              ["_print":protected]=>
              bool(false)
              ["ajaxResponse"]=>
              array(0) {
              }
              ["urlPath"]=>
              array(4) {
                [0]=>
                string(7) "civicrm"
                [1]=>
                string(7) "contact"
                [2]=>
                string(4) "view"
                [3]=>
                string(4) "case"
              }
              ["useLivePageJS"]=>
              NULL
              ["_action"]=>
              int(4)
              ["_id"]=>
              int(5)
              ["_context"]=>
              string(4) "case"
            }
            ["_output":protected]=>
            int(1)
            ["_prefix":protected]=>
            NULL
            ["_dynamicAction":protected]=>
            bool(false)
            ["_case"]=>
            int(5)
          }
        }
      }
      [4]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(90) "/var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Case/Page/Tab.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(111)
        ["function"]=>
        string(3) "run"
        ["class"]=>
        string(28) "CRM_Core_Selector_Controller"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [5]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(90) "/var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Case/Page/Tab.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(180)
        ["function"]=>
        string(4) "view"
        ["class"]=>
        string(17) "CRM_Case_Page_Tab"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [6]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(88) "/var/www/wordpress_solocal_energy/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(312)
        ["function"]=>
        string(3) "run"
        ["class"]=>
        string(17) "CRM_Case_Page_Tab"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(4) {
            [0]=>
            string(7) "civicrm"
            [1]=>
            string(7) "contact"
            [2]=>
            string(4) "view"
            [3]=>
            string(4) "case"
          }
          [1]=>
          NULL
        }
      }
```

Comment: Does "organize case" mean "manage case"? Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: I can see from the stacktrace it's for `CRM_Event_BAO_ParticipantPayment` and the searchValue field is null when looking for `contribution_id`. I don't know how that is connected to manage case in your install though. Do you maybe have participant payment contributions filed on cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your backtrace it looks like, you have a activity of type payment or refund that is suppose to have link to contribution in civicrm_activity.source_record_id which is unfortunately set as NULL.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful hints!
Indeed there was a payment activity which was ill defined, though CiviCase didn't accept simply deleting it (the activity type "payment"/"Zahlung" kept reappearing over and over).
In the end, I managed to get CiviCase running (and vastly extending its usefulness) by installing CompuCorps CiviCase extension: https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicase

Answer (score 0):

A solution for not having a `civicrm_activity.source_record_id` tied to the contribution is to create a new activity type of e.g. "Legacy Payment" and switch those activity type ID's. Encountered this on a DB migration.

> Source Record ID: Artificial FK to original transaction (e.g.
> contribution) IF it is not an Activity.